# Is there any viewWillAppear like-function in Sencha Touch

Tags: javascript, extjs, sencha-touch

I am trying to call a function every time when a view shows up. but it only gets called for first time and thenafter it doesn't. Is there any event-function like viewWillAppear of iOS. I am using **'initialize'** event function and it gets called only once. Please help.

**View:**

```
Ext.define('Abc.view.abc', {
 extend: 'Ext.List',
 xtype: 'runningList',
 requires: ['Abc.store.InstancesStore','Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',],

config: {
title: 'Running',
id: 'instanceList',/*
itemTpl: '<div class="serached_listview">'+ 
        '<div>{key}  {key} </div>' +
        '<div><b>{key}</b> </div>' +
        '<div>  {key}</div>' +
        '</div>'
        ,*/
        store: 'RunningInstanceStore',
           listeners: [{
                fn: 'initialize',
                 event: 'initialize'
            }
    ]
  }
});
```

Controller:

```
 Ext.define("Abc.controller.InstancesController", {
extend: 'Ext.app.Controller',
requires: [ 'Ext.data.JsonP','Ext.device.Connection'],
config: {
    refs: { 
        main: 'mainpanel',
                     Instances: '#instanceList',
        ListView: 'runningList'
    },
    control: {
        Instances: {
            initialize: 'initializePanel',
            activate:'initializePanel'
        },
        "runningInstancesList": {
            disclose: 'listViewAccessoryTapped',
            itemtap: 'listViewTapped'
        }
    }
},
listViewAccessoryTapped:  function(view, index, item, e) {
    if(Ext.device.Connection.isOnline())
        console.log('Internet connection is available.');
    else
        console.log('Internet connection is not available.');

},
listViewTapped:  function(view, index, item, e) {




},

initializePanel: function() { 
    console.log('Hi');     **////////////////Called only once...**

}
});
```

Comment: Did you try the `show` event lisenter? http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.dataview.List-event-show

Answer (score 0):

In ExtJS there is component.beforeactivate, which fires each time before a component is activated

http://docs.sencha.com/ext-js/4-1/#!/api/Ext.AbstractComponent-event-beforeactivate

However, in Touch, there appears to be only container.activate, which looks like it is fired after a child component is activated

http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Container-event-activate

Comment: I have tried all show(), painted(), activate(), beforeactivate(), but no one is helping mr right now. plz help.

Answer (score 0):

One of these event handlers (instead of initialize) should help you:

Painted
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-event-painted

Show
http://docs.sencha.com/touch/2-1/#!/api/Ext.Component-event-show

Ideally these events should be handled in controller like this(one of many ways)

```
        '#instanceList': {
            show        : 'onListShow'
        }
```

but you can alternatively add listener to your view like this:

```
Ext.define('Abc.view.abc', {
  extend: 'Ext.List',
  xtype: 'runningList',
  requires: ['Abc.store.InstancesStore','Ext.data.proxy.JsonP',],

  config: {
    title: 'Running',
    id: 'instanceList',
    store: 'RunningInstanceStore',
    listeners: {
      show  : function(me, opts){
        // Do whatever you want here
      }
    }
  }
});
```

Comment: Where should I use these functions as I am using it in place of intialize. it doesn't get called.

Code:  

       listeners: [{
                fn: 'initialize',
                 event: 'show'
            }

Comment: I have tried all show(), painted(), activate(), beforeactivate(), but no one is helping mr right now. show function gets called for first time. plz help.